# Cassandra inter DC sync over VPN on GCP

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have an VPN between the company network 172.16.0.0/16 and GCP 10.164.0.0/24

On GCP there is a cassandra cluster running with 3 instances. These instances get dynamical local ip adresses - for example *10.4.7.4* , *10.4.6.5*, *10.4.3.4*.

My issue: from the company network I cannot access 10.4x addresses as the tunnel works only for 10.164.0.0/24.

I tried setting up an LB service on 10.164.0.100 with the cassandra nodes behind. This doesnt work: when I configure that ip adress as seed node on local cluster, it gets an reply from one of the 10.4.x ip addresses, which it doesnt have in its seed list.

I need advice how to setup inter DC sync in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IP addresses which K8s assign to Pods and Services are [internal cluster-only addresses](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) which are not accessible from outside of the cluster. It is possible by some CNI to create connection between in-cluster addresses and external networks, but I don't think that is a good idea in your case.

You need to expose your Cassandra using [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/) with NodePort or LoadBalancer type. That is another one [answer](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/issues/48) with a same solution from Kubernetes Github.

If you will add a Service with type NodePort, your Cassandra will be available on a selected port on all Kubernetes nodes.

If you will choose LoadBalancer, Kubernetes will create for you Cloud Load Balancer which will be an entrypoint for Cassandra. Because you have a VPN to your VPC, I think you will need an [Internal Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing).

Comment: Well I did create an internal loadbalancer already - but as I mentioned that doesnt help: as soon as I configure the IP adress of the LB on my company datacenter, the connection is made and proxied to the underlying seed. That seed answers with its own IP adress - this makes the handshake between the cassandra clusters fail, as the internal IP adress of the seed in not on the seed list (it contains only the LB ip address)

Comment: What might work: instead of running cassandra inside of kubernetes I could setup exclusive VMs for my instances. Cross check shows that I can access an single VM instance in my cluster from inside of a POD in kubernetes. As VMs can be assigned static internal IPs in my desired range, that should work. Downside: the cassandra instances would no longer be managed by kubernetes, no auto restart etc

Comment: Yes, you can do it. The problem is - Cassandra announce addresses which it binds, but actually that is not an external addresses which available from outside. It is not a cloud-native application and do not support schemes with balancers etc. You can try to use hostNetwork mode and port binding 1:1 for Cassandra pods then it will announce to a client nodes addresses which might help.